# how to get final pageController.page value in flutter

Tags: flutter, controller, pagecontrol

I have below code which was working before but as the nature of the remaining code have changed, this is not working anymore.

I need `pageController.page` value to add `background` and `borderColor` to button in `listView` under `GestureDetector`.

issue is if I remove the comment from below code, I only get the first value which is in `decimal points` and is not like `1,2,3,4,5` in `double`. this results in no changes as I am comparing the `currentPageValue` to `index` in `ListView.builder`.

I can get the `background & borderColor` set on the `GestureDetector onTap()` but then I loose the current `scroll position` for listView which is another matter.

What am I doing wrong ?

Listener code :

```
void initState() {
    setUp();
    pageController
      ..addListener(() {
        // setState(() {
        currentPageValue = pageController.page;
        // });
        print(currentPageValue);
      });
    super.initState();
  }
```

output:

```
flutter: 0.37981
flutter: 0.734
flutter: 0.9924299999999998
flutter: 1.0

flutter: 1.166665
flutter: 1.3333300000000001
flutter: 1.4166599999999998
flutter: 1.49999
flutter: 1.5833300000000001
flutter: 1.6666600000000003
flutter: 1.75
flutter: 1.91671
flutter: 1.999995
flutter: 2.0

flutter: 1.91679
flutter: 1.833465
flutter: 1.7501250000000002
flutter: 1.66679
flutter: 1.583455
flutter: 1.50013
flutter: 1.333445
flutter: 1.250125
flutter: 1.083455
flutter: 1.0

flutter: 1.16666
flutter: 1.33332
flutter: 1.49999
flutter: 1.6666600000000003
flutter: 1.8333199999999998
flutter: 2.0

flutter: 2.3333299999999997
flutter: 2.8983
flutter: 3.0
```

Comment: Do you want only int value of current page?

Comment: @NikhilVadoliya pageController.page gives the value in `double` and the issue is I get this value but if I use setState then the first value from the `transition iteration` is only return as you can see above. Major I have notice is that this is the issue since I shifted to `FutureBuilder` in the code. previously I was calling the api at `init`. again shifted to it but then I am still stuck with the placeholder Issue which in itself is a different matter.

Comment: Can you share your UI which you want?

Comment: ofcourse not @NikhilVadoliya ! also I have already mentioned `background and BorderColor` is what I am changing.

Answer (score 0):

I'm manually checking if that value is int or not.

```
 _pageController = PageController()
      ..addListener(() {
        if (_pageController.page != null && _pageController.page!.isInt) {
          setState(() {
            currentPage = _pageController.page!.round();
          });
          print(currentPage);
        }
      });
```

And for isInt

```
extension NumExtensions on num {
  bool get isInt => (this % 1) == 0;
}
```